# several domains using the same core backend/frontend files

Tags: dns

I have a few domains hosted on the same server.  These domains contain very similar types of data(similar to stackoverflow.com, stackexchange.com, serverfault.com).  They all have the same idea, except minor things are different like images, titles, etc.

How can I use the same base code(like a php/javascript include, or even database) on each of these domains without copy/paste and having many copies to update when i make a change?

any advice would be great!

edit:
for a novice like myself in this department, where would I look to set variables in the virtual host which would tell the code which template/database my code should use for my specific host?

What kind of server setup or access would i need to have for this to be configured properly?

I am using PHP and MySQL for my sites.

If a thorough answer cannot be supplied, direct me as to how I can contact my hosting provider in such a way that they can understand and help me configure what I desire!

Answer (score 2):

Set a variable in the virtual host that tells the code which template, database, etc. the code should use for that specific virtual host.

Comment: soo, i have this option to enable VPS service.  I'm new to server configurations and stuff, is this something i'd need to look into?

Comment: No. You'd need to look into configuring your web server.

Comment: guess i'm not sure where to look to configure this.  it may be out my league for now, but maybe you could be a bit more detailed/informative in your answer

Comment: Only if you can be a bit more detailed/informative in your question.

Comment: And there's still information missing. This is something that has to be done in the web server.